# How do I sum up 2 dimensional array, ex index 0+index0

Tags: javascript

I encountered a problem! 
for example! here is my 2 dimensional array: `var array=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]];`
and my desired outcome is : `[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[6,9,12,15]]`

the [6,9,12,15] came from adding the same index numbers of the previous inner arrays. (`ex 1+2+3, 2+3+4, 3+4+5, 4+5+6` more clear :  `index 1 + index 1+ index1 produces 9`)

I am so confused so far, the closes i did was to sum up `[1,2,3,4][2,3,4,5][3,4,5,6]`, but I cant seem to do something with each and individual numbers :(

The question requested me to do nested for loops, So i cant use any thing like reduce, map, flatten, etc...

Comment: Promise it's not any homework or test, one of my friend came up with this problem himself and figured it'll be a challenge for me since I'm learning arrays.  I won't be here if I didn't get really stuck, sorry I find ur comment a little rude.

Comment: The issue remains, what have you tried?

Comment: As a beginner, please make a conscious effort to take criticism constructively. @j0869's asking for your code is hardly rude. It's practically the slogan of SO. You should always present your work before asking for help in the future. Please keep this in mind. Welcome to SO

Comment: I am sorry as I am very new to stack overflow, and I didn't know I should post my code in my post, but I did reply to some of the answers i saw down below, my point is that this wasn't a test or homework, if he explained this like you did I would apologize and post my work. He sounded like I was cheating that's all. Again, I apologize for not posting my code , but to nothing else.

Comment: Just to show my respect to stackoverflow , here is what I had:     Function sumup(array){var result =[]  var sum=0. for (var I = 0 I < array.length I ++){for var j = 0 j < array[i].length; j++ ){ sum+=array[j][i]....

Comment: My computer is out of battery, please ignore syntax errors as I hand typed this on my cellphone . Thanks again for those who helped me with this, I've learned a lot from each and everyone of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this way:https://jsfiddle.net/0L0h7cat/

```
var array=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]];
    var array4 = [];
    for (j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {
    var num =0;
     for(i=0;i< array.length;i++){
    num += array[i][j];
    }
    array4.push(num);
    }
    array.push(array4);
    alert(array);
```

Comment: Wow thanks , now I know where I did wrong, I started with the y axis first which is I<array.length then j<array[i].length, which totally mess up my whole story, thanks again!

Comment: Then I tried to push array[j][i] and always came up undefined , because j is greater than i! Yes I'm glad I figured that out

Comment: function sumup(array){
  
  var result=[];
  var sum=0;
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    
    for(var j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
      sum+=array[j][i];
      
      
    }
  
  result.push(sum);
  }
  
  array.push(result);
  return array;
  
}

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the outer array and the inner arrays and add the values to the result array `array[3]`.

```js
var array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (b, i) {
        array[3] = array[3] || [];
        array[3][i] = (array[3][i] || 0) + b;
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/0L0h7cat/

```
var array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 4, 5, 6]
];
var sumArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
  sumArr[i] = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
    sumArr[i] += array[j][i];
}

array.push(sumArr);
```

Comment: function sumup(array){
  
  var result=[];
  var sum=0;
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    
    for(var j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
      sum+=array[j][i];
      
      
    }
  
  result.push(sum);
  }
  
  array.push(result);
  return array;
  
}

Comment: i see my sum was at the wrong place, and i and j vars are reversed, no wonder always came up undefined for [i][j], thanks for this answer, learnt alot!

Answer (score 0):

This is how -

```js
    var array=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]];
    var array2=[]
    for (var i = array[0].length;i--;) {
        var sum=0;
        for (var j = array.length; j--;) {
            sum=sum+array[j][i];
        }
     array2.push(sum)
}

array.push(array2.reverse());

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(array) + '</pre>');
```

But I'm sure there are more elegant methods. I'm just learning by answering questions myself.

Comment: function sumup(array){
  
  var result=[];
  var sum=0;
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    
    for(var j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
      sum+=array[j][i];
      
      
    }
  
  result.push(sum);
  }
  
  array.push(result);
  return array;
  
}

Comment: i had i running as y axis first then j as x axis, and tried to push [j][i], which left i undefined, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), this will work:-

```js
var array = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[2, 3, 4, 5],[3, 4, 5, 6]];

var count = [];
array.forEach(x => x.forEach((y, i) => count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + y));
array.push(count);

console.log(array);
```

**NOTE:** Not cross browser support yet.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach with just conventional `for` loops

```js
var input = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6]];
    
function getSumOfArrayOfArrays(inputArray) {
  var length = inputArray.length;
  var result = [];
  for(var i=0; i<length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<=3; j++){
      result[j] = result[j] ? result[j] + inputArray[i][j] : inputArray[i][j];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var output = getSumOfArrayOfArrays(input); // [6,9,12,15]

var desiredOutput = input;
desiredOutput.push(output)

document.write(JSON.stringify(desiredOutput));

// [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[6,9,12,15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid writing nested for loops.

```js
var arrayOfArrays=[
    [1,2,3,4],
    [2,3,4,5],
    [3,4,5,6]
];

//define a function to extend the Array prototype
Array.prototype.add = function(otherArray){
    var result = [];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        result.push( this[i] + otherArray[i] )
    }

    return result;
};

//reduce array of arrays to get the result array `sum`
var sum = arrayOfArrays.reduce(function(arrayA, arrayB){
    //`arrayA`+`arrayB` becomes another `arrayA`
    return arrayA.add(arrayB)
});

//put `sum` back to `arrayOfArrays`
arrayOfArrays.push(sum);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arrayOfArrays) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: "The question requested me to do nested for loops, So i cant use any thing like reduce, map, flatten, etc..." You had some cool ideas though.

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful , I got the idea, and I knew where I was wrong! I had my 2counters reversed and I declared my sum var at a wrong place ! Thanks again for your help!